# Electrical problem with a Toyota vitz 2009 automatic transmission

Tags: electrical, toyota, automatic-transmission, power-steering

i have been having these issues with my car lately i will  try to explain them as best as i can here are all the problems listed:

1. the indicator lights work but disappears as soon as i put my feet on the break pedal and starts working again once i let go off the brake pedal.
2. the gear indicator on the dashboard(P,R,N,D,S,B) blinks every time i start the car and doesn't stop blinking and then when i put my feet on the break pedal it disappears all the way and doesn't show anything and when my foot is off the pedal it starts blinking again
3. the head lights kind of dim and brighten as the same interval as the gear indicators are blinking and once again when i put my feet on the break pedal the lights just dim
4. the engine sound also gets louder and less louder as the same interval as the gear indicators are blinking kind of like when you press and let go the gas pedal continuously the sound feels like that and also when you press the break pedal it feels like you are pressing the gas pedal you can hear the engine working as if you were giving it gas and when you change the gear from neutral to drive while pressing the break pedal the car kind of jumps but doesn't go anywhere since your foot is on the break pedal.
5. the battery light on the dashboard comes and goes sometimes
6. the check engine light also comes and goes like once a day or so,it stays for like 10-20 seconds and the light goes off
7. when you start the car and you are not moving and try to turn the steering wheel its gets very stiff you would have to put a lot of force on it to turn and when i put it on neutral and give it gas it goes normal as it was, this only happens when the car is not moving or when i am moving really slow

and the weird part is all of this problem came like suddenly overnight they didn't all come gradually all of them just came at once.

so i would really appreciate it if someone could just give me a suggestion on what maybe causing the problems.

Thanks

Comment: welcome to mvm stack exchange. that definitely sounds electrical. your stiff turning issue is the power-steering being disabled. I've encountered similar shutdowns (on a different make/model) due to alternator not charging or not regulating voltage appropriately -- the electrical accessories started shuttting down one by one suddenly. your brake pedal activates (all) rear lights, which could cut off power to the small ones. the rate of blinking can be affected by the number of accessories still on the circuit. Check your voltage on the battery perhaps? Don't go on the road until fixed.

Comment: reading this over, I'm not sure my low-voltage theory holds in combination with your engine revving when you depress the brake pedal. that said, checking the battery is a relatively good starting point when sorting out systemic electrical issues.